# How to remove part of url using python?

Tags: python, regex, url, url-modification

I have a problem. I can't figure out a way to do this so I'm asking for  someone to help.

I have URL like below:

```
https://abc.xyz/f/b/go_cc_Jpterxvid_avi_mp4
```

And, I want to remove the last part of URL and change /f/ with /d/ so that I can get the URL to be like below:

```
https://abc.xyz/d/b
```

Keep in mind the prefix `/b`. It changes regular python.
I have tried this below based on url answer but it didsn't work for me.

```py
newurl = oldurl.replace('/f/','/d/').rsplit("/", 1)[0])
```

Comment: you mean  `https://abc.xyz/f/b` is static word or change some time

Comment: An option using regex [`/[^/]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/8RqbPg/1) and replace with an empty string. This matches the last foward slash until the end of the string.

Comment: /b i change regular it's not static

Comment: /b only or /f/b

Comment: just /b the only thing that it change

Answer (score 2):

A more efficient way of splitting is to use `rsplit` and set `maxsplit` to 1. This saves you the time and hassle rejoining the string.

```
old_url = "https://abc.xyz/f/b/go_cc_Jpterxvid_avi_mp4"
url = old_url.rsplit("/", 1)[0]
# print(url) => https://abc.xyz/f/b
```

Comment: i have updated the question  i have tried to add ur answer but i didnt' succeed newurl = oldurl.replace('/f/','/d/').rsplit("/", 1)[0])

Comment: @MouhcinIuoanid it works fine https://ideone.com/9V9w0i. I can see from your comment that you had an extra ) at the end.

Answer (score 1):

This what you want?

```
'/'.join(url.split('/')[:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need regex for this.
The following will work for a link:

```
k = "https://abc.xyz/f/b/go_cc_Jpterxvid_avi_mp4"
print("/".join(k.split("/")[:-1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

After [split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) or [rsplit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit), sometimes you will want and need to specify and get the list of element from the front then [join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) them and [replace()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) `f` with `d` as shown below:

```py
url = "https://abc.xyz/f/b/go_cc_Jpterxvid_avi_mp4"
new_url = "/".join(url.split("/")[:5]).replace("f", "d")
print(new_url)
```

```py
url = "https://abc.xyz/f/b/go_cc_Jpterxvid_avi_mp4"
new_url = "/".join(url.rsplit("/")[:5]).replace("f", "d")
print(new_url)
```

Output:

```
https://abc.xyz/f/b
```